# App rejected due to Guideline 3.2 - Business, what to do next?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, b2b

My app got rejected due to

> Guideline 3.2 - Business
>
> We found that your app is not appropriate for the App Store since it
>   is designed specifically for AppName.
>
> It would be more appropriate to distribute and sell your app as a
>   [custom B2B app](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/), directly to your business customers, through the
>   [Volume Purchase Program](https://www.apple.com/business/vpp/). You can find additional information
>   regarding the Volume Purchase Program and the Custom B2B App Store in
>   [iTunes Connect Developer Help](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev275598f16).

Now I also join the [Volume Purchase Program](https://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) with another apple id but now I don't now what to do next, How I can distribute my app ?

Comment: whats your app about in general? and is it targetting a specific company?

Comment: Yes it is specific for some company there is no registration page there login credential are provided by admin

Comment: @VarunNaharia - did you read the documentation on creating and distributing B2B apps? If you did, try to explain your question better, as the documentation makes it seem pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @DonMag will you please send me the link for the documentation that you are talking about

Comment: @VarunNaharia - you included the link in your question: [custom B2B app](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/). You design and create your app... you set the pricing... you select *custom B2B distribution* in iTuneConnect. The specific company you built the app for then enrolls in VPP, purchases copies of your app and distributes it to its users/employees.

Comment: @DonMag thanks I understood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AppStore is a public portal that is meant for all the people. If your App is to be on the AppStore, then a wide majority of people should be able to use your application.

If your app is only for a specific company, then it wont fit to be in the AppStore since many people will see it, download it, find it useless and delete it (since they have no access to anything, it's a waste of time for them).

I had 3 clients who wanted apps specific for their company. I send them the app OTA (Over the Air)

My suggestion is to let the company employees install the app OTA (Over the air) where you send them a link to download the app and it downloads itself on their device. This also provides better security since only the people eligible to download the app would have the download link.

After all you don't want people downloading the app, finding it useless and down voting it since it was a waste of time for them

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know the point why the app rejected but now my issue is how I can send app to users, currently app is running only on device those are registered on apple account and that also limited to 100 device. Please let know the solution how I can send app to users

Comment: If you have an enterprise membership then you can create an enterprise build for distribution via MDM. If you are not employed by the end client then you can distribute via the B2B process to them and they can use their MDM to distribute to their devices.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you please explain in detail ?, what things are needed and how to create ipa for this process I also join Volume Purchase Program, Don't what do next please help

Comment: you can use a tool called installr as well

Comment: For VPP you just upload the app as normal but flag the app as a B2B app on iTunesConnect under "pricing and availability" for your app. The customer can then provide their VPP id and you can authorise the purchase

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute your app to users by email

Your app rejected means you have uploaded the app for review,
here the best option for you is using test flight as you already done the uploading and provisining things which is required for distributing on test flight
[image]

just click on the test flight tab and explore a little bit
eventually you just have add email then a link will be sent to that email with your app link

Comment: Test flight is build for testing purposes and not for distributing, the best option would be gonig for a enterprise account with ota installations.

Comment: Agreed, TestFlight builds expire in 90 days, so TestFlight is not ideal for production, you will at least need to upload a new app binary once every 90 days - if you don't, the app will become unavailable.